# Identifying Facebook Status Update using C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have made an automated test to login to Facebook and make a status update.
I am however stuck with two problems:

1. The entire status text doesn't get typed with sendkeys() function.
2. Identifying the appearance of the status right after it appears in the home feed

Here is the code sample I used:

```
IWebElement query5 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("u_0_1d"));//this is to find the status field
query5.Click();
WebDriverWait wait5 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
query5.SendKeys("Status Update made by test automation using Selenium");
WebDriverWait wait6 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
IWebElement query6 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.clearfix button.selected"));
query6.Click();

/*I tried to check whether or not the status appears in the homefeed by executing the following code, but it doesn't work. */

IWebElement query7 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.fcg a.nazarah div.userContent")); 

/*i used my partial href text of my profile url which has a term nazarah*/
```

Problem 1: only the following sub text is typed in the status box:
"date made by test automation using Selenium"

Problem 2: usually when you post a status, it appears just below the status update field. How can I identify and confirm it using selenium c#?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some elements’ html ids you rely on is pointing on wrong elements or not persistent.
Facebook dynamically generates Html Ids for some elements, so it would be much better to identify web-elements with different attributes.

I’ve posted long source code below, and here are some highlights:

Problem 1:

```
txtMessage.SendKeys("Hello! This is an update\n");
txtMessage.SendKeys("From automated script " + messageGuid);
```

You can use a character \n inside string to put a new line.

Problem 2:
You can count the number of current user posts and wait until it is increased.

```
while (currentMessagesCount <= previousMessagesCount)
{
    userMessagesList = driver.FindElementsByCssSelector(PostLocators.userPostsList_CssSelector);
    currentMessagesCount = userMessagesList.Count();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Also, I would like to recommend a tool which aims to debug locators for Selenium Webdriver – [SWD Page Recorder](https://github.com/dzhariy/swd-recorder/releases); here is [a short overview](http://unmesh.me/2013/08/29/pageobject-generator-utility-for-selenium-webdriver/).

#### Full Source code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        //Locators: Generated with SWD Page Recorder; Template=[CSharp] Locator constants in the static class
        public static class LoginLocators
        {
            public const string txtEmail_XPath = @"id(""email"")";
            public const string txtPassword_XPath = @"id(""pass"")";
            public const string btnLogin_XPath = @"id(""loginbutton"")";
        }

        public static class PostLocators
        {
            public const string txtWhatsOnYourMind_XPath = @"//textarea[contains(@title,""What's on your mind?"")]";
            public const string btnPost_XPath = @"//button[contains(text(), 'Post')]";
            public const string userPostsList_CssSelector = @"div.userContentWrapper";
        }
        // ====

#region Login and Password
        static string userLogin = "googleplus@gmail.com";
        static string userPassword = "pAAASSSSWWWrd";
#endregion

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Url = "https://www.facebook.com";

            // Log-in to Facebook
            var txtLogin    = driver.FindElementByXPath(LoginLocators.txtEmail_XPath);
            var txtPassword = driver.FindElementByXPath(LoginLocators.txtPassword_XPath);
            var btnLogIn    = driver.FindElementByXPath(LoginLocators.btnLogin_XPath);

            txtLogin.SendKeys(userLogin);
            txtPassword.SendKeys(userPassword);
            btnLogIn.Click();

            // Go to F.b. Updates
            driver.Url = "https://www.facebook.com/?sk=nf";

            // Find Elements on Fb. Updates Page
            var txtMessage = driver.FindElementByXPath(PostLocators.txtWhatsOnYourMind_XPath);
            var btnPost = driver.FindElementByXPath(PostLocators.btnPost_XPath);

            var userMessagesList = driver.FindElementsByCssSelector(PostLocators.userPostsList_CssSelector);
            int previousMessagesCount = userMessagesList.Count();
            Console.WriteLine("User messages before: {0}", previousMessagesCount);

            string messageGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            // Perform Post Update
            /* Problem 1: only the following sub text is typed in the status box: 
             * "date made by test automation using Selenium" */
            txtMessage.SendKeys("Hello! This is an update\n");
            txtMessage.SendKeys("From automated script " + messageGuid);
            btnPost.Click();

            int currentMessagesCount = previousMessagesCount;

            /* Problem 2: usually when you post a status, it appears just below 
             * the status update field. 
             * How can I identify and confirm it using selenium c#? */

            // Wait untill new message is added
            while (currentMessagesCount <= previousMessagesCount)
            {
                userMessagesList = driver.FindElementsByCssSelector(PostLocators.userPostsList_CssSelector);
                currentMessagesCount = userMessagesList.Count();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("User messages after: {0}", currentMessagesCount);

            // Just for demo purpose :D
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

            driver.Quit();

        }
    }
}
```

#### Demo Video:

http://www.youtube.com/embed/_VVcc4zZiwE?vq=hd720